# Segmentation fault when using fgets()

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am trying to store a list of sentences in a two dimensional pointer array. The code below gives a segmentation fault just after loop is evlauted (I check with a printf statement; no statements inside the loop is executed):

```
int main( int argc, char** argv){

  char *inputarray[MAX_LINE];
  int count = 0;

  //char cpy[MAX_LENGTH] <---- This one doesn't work either                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  char *cpy = (char*) calloc (MAX_LENGTH, sizeof(char));

  while ( count <= MAX_LINE && fgets(cpy, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)){

    int str_len = strlen(cpy);
    cpy[--str_len] = '\0';

    inputarray[count++] = reverse(cpy, str_len);

  }

  printOutput(inputarray, count);

  return 0;
```

}

Have been trying to debug for 3+ hours now with no avail. Help anyone?

Comment: What is MAX_LENGTH? And what are you feeding into this? Can you show the first MAX_LENGTH + 1 characters of the input?

Comment: Can you show what the reverse function is doing? A couple of other notes: 1) don't cast the return of calloc (when using c). It can mask important warnings and there is no need 2) fgets will already null terminate the string, but it looks like you are truncating off that last character of the input, is that intentional?

Comment: Yeah getting rid of \n

Answer (score 1):

You have allocated only `MAX_LINE` elements to array of pointers to the char.

- Since array index starts from `0`.
- Use the condition (`count < MAX_LINE`) and not (`count <= MAX_LINE`)

Example:
Suppose you have allocated `*inputaray[5];`
This is what happens,

```
count=0;    //1st sentence 
count=1;    //2nd sentence
count=2;    //3rd sentence
count=3;    //4th sentence
count=4;    //5th sentence
```

In the code above,

```
 count=5;   //which is <=5
```

and thus tries to store the input string into an invalid memory.

Comment: I think my answer is right. But I'm new to Stackoverflow answering.

Comment: Okay go on. But +1 for my answer.

Comment: Just make a change yourself that `inputarray` is not a `char array` there . It is `array of pointer to char` which he declares .

Comment: @ameyCU Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not `pointers to char array` just `array of pointers to char` . Both have different meanings .

Comment: It doesn't even run the first time. MAX_LINE is 5000